# How do I add text "Max Characters" to JavaScript Counter?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript counter that goes up to 125 characters. Once 125 is reached, the counter displays "125". How can I have it say "Max Characters" instead?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
if (field.value.length > maxlimit) 
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
// otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
else 
countfield.value = field.value.length;
}
</script>

<center>
<form name=myform action="#">
<font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> 
( You may enter up to 125 characters. )<br>
<textarea name=message wrap=physical cols=28 rows=4 
 onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);" 
 onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);"
    ></textarea>
<br>
<input readonly type=text name=remLen size=3 maxlength=3 value="0"> characters total</font>
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: Then answer you have choosen it's right, but the small letter in your question says "instead" (about 125 displayed), the code of the answer will display 125 when you reach that number and will display the message just after you go over that number (next keypress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function textCounter (field, countfield, maxlimit) {
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        countfield.value = 'max characters';
    } else { // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
        countfield.value = field.value.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! any chance you know how to update the code if there is already text in there? for example, if i come to a PHP form page that has 10 characters filled in the text box already, the form still says 0 until i enter something. any way to have the counter say "10" (if there are 10 characters filled in)

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like this instead: **http://jsfiddle.net/9AeT4/**

It lets the user know how many are left as they type.  See fiddle for it in action.  No need for jQuery either.  Basic JavaScript.

```
<textarea id="remLen" name="remLen" onkeyup="textCounter('remLen','remLen_count',125);">Some initial text</textarea>
<div id="remLen_count"></div>

textCounter=function(textarea, countdown, maxlimit)
{
  textareaid = document.getElementById(textarea);
  if (textareaid.value.length > maxlimit)
    textareaid.value = textareaid.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
  else
    document.getElementById(countdown).innerHTML = ''+(maxlimit-textareaid.value.length)+' characters left';
}

/*to correctly set the chars left initially if there is initial text in the field*/
textCounter('remLen','remLen_count',125);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/5e4we/3/). I used jQuery because, well, why not?

The HTML would look like this:

```
<form name="myform">
    <textarea id="myMessage"></textarea>
</form>
<font id="characterCounter"></font>
```

And the script would be:

```
$("#myMessage").keyup(function(){
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    if (length != 125 && length < 125)
        $("#characterCounter").html(length + " of 125 characters. " + (125 - length) + " left!");
    else if (length > 125)
        $("#characterCounter").html((length - 125) + " extra characters!");
    else
        $("#characterCounter").html("Max characters!");
}).keyup();
```

Basically, each time you press a key, it updates the `<font>` tag with the amount of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your js function **textCounter** to this if see if works as you want

```
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {

    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    (field.value.length==125)?countfield.value="Max. Characters.":countfield.value=field.value.length;
}
```

it works, bu I don't know if cover your question.